# HyperLedger composer v0.20.8 error when starting the business network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to deploy locally my business network, so I exported my project from the composer-playground and installed the business network with this command

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile fruit-trace@0.0.2-deploy.11.bna
```

and then when trying to start the business network running this command

```
composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.2-deploy.11 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card
```

got this error

> "Error: Error trying to start a business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot
>   get package for chaincode (tutorial-network:0.0.2-deploy.11))"

Comment: The network name and version will be installed as specified in the bna file. most probably the network name or version in the start command is wrong. to check the network name and version in the bna file use "composer archive list" command.

Answer (score 0):

Check for "name" and "version" in package.json inside your business network archive. You should use the same name and version when running the start command.

Comment: Checked it and found this .. 
{"name":"fruit-trace","author":"author","description":"Start from scratch with a blank business network","version":"0.0.2-deploy.11",

Comment: So your command should look something like this:

composer network start --networkName fruit-trace --networkVersion 0.0.2-deploy.11 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

Remember that 'name' in package.json refers to the name of the business network.

Comment: also, I've changed it but still got command failed, in fact, tutorial-network is the directory name in which there's the .bna archive